# text box doesn't update when I push the button

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have example here: [code example](http://jsfiddle.net/evngjvLc/2/).

HTML code:

```
<input id="uploadFile" placeholder="Choose File" disabled="disabled" />
<div class="file-upload btn btn-primary">
    <span>Upload</span> 
    <br> 
    <input id="uploadBtn" class="upload" type="file">
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.btn {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.file-upload input.upload {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.file-upload {
    margin-left: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.btn-primary {
    background-color: #428bca;
    border-color: #357ebd;
    color: #fff;
}
```

JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementById("uploadBtn").onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
};
```

In JSFiddle site, when I push the upload button, the text box are updated,
but when I copy the code to files, and run it under Firefox Mozilla,
the text box doesn't update.

I take reference from this site: [How to Style a HTML file upload button in Pure CSS](http://geniuscarrier.com/how-to-style-a-html-file-upload-button-in-pure-css/)

Any suggestions?

Comment: I assume this is a linking problem between your HTML and Javascript files. Did you put a script tag in the HTML for the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS does not work since the `uploadBtn` is not created when you are trying to add the `onchange` listener. Try waiting for the window to load.

```
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById("uploadBtn").onchange = function () {
      document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
   };
};
```

Comment: wow! thanks, you are fast. it work. i never was think about that. (i will give the answer for you. I can't give it after 6 minuets. that mean you are very fast! :) )